# StyleCop for ReSharper 4.5 no longer available

Tags: resharper, stylecop

Due to certain library dependencies I still need to use ReSharper 4.5 with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (Professional Edition).

I also need to use StyleCop.

For this edition of ReSharper 4.5  I need to use StyleCop 4.3.1.3 which I can get here 
http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/48036

However, I cannot find the StyleCop for ReSharper 4.5 anywhere.

All the links lead to dead end here
http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/

Can anybody provide me with the working link to the place where I can download this StyleCop for ReSharper 4.5 plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I'm right, but I found this site:

http://stylecop.forresharper.org/download.htm

Please comment if it's the wrong version than I will continue my search

Edit:
I found this link:
[www.resharperstylecop.com/release/4.5/StyleCop.For.ReSharper.Setup.v4.5.15.0.msi](http://www.resharperstylecop.com/release/4.5/StyleCop.For.ReSharper.Setup.v4.5.15.0.msi)

You can not reach it from the outsite but the versions.txt with the link was still there.

Comment: It is the correct version that I am looking for, however; this site has only links to the codeplex site (see link above) which no longer provides this version of StyleCop plugin for ReSharper 4.5.

Comment: Yes, I can reach the file, however; during the installation of the StyleCop plugin I get warning that this is a plugin for ReSharper 4.5.1274.1. The available version from the official web site is ReSharper 4.5.1288.2 http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-280. Do you know if there is StyleCop plugin for ReSharper 4.5.1288.2 as well?

Comment: Even when you install this version it requires StyleCop v4.3.2.1 which is also not available from here http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/48036. The version you can get is StyleCop 4.3.3.0.

Comment: To sum up I have 
Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Professional v 9.0.30729.4462 QFE,
StyleCop 4.3.3.0,
ReSharper 4.5.1288.2,
And I need a version of StyleCop for ReSharper that would work with the above products. It could be just the *.dll file that I can drop in the ReSharper’s plugin directory.

Comment: I tested that you can still use the above configuration with StyleCop For ReSharper 5.0.14714.1 from here http://stylecop.forresharper.org/download/5.0/StyleCop.For.ReSharper-5.0.14714.1.zip. However, you will get some exceptions that you can ignore.

Answer (score 0):

"StyleCop for ReSharper" also still have source codes open at CodePlex, so it should be possible to download it and compile by yourself.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get the source code from here https://StyleCopForReSharper.svn.codeplex.com/svn using for example Tortoise SVN (http://tortoisesvn.net/). However, the code does not compile from the box and I am currently stuck with an error: “Error 1: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.StyleCop.StyleCopRunner'”
I would appreciate if somebody could compile this solution and provide me with the resultant *.dll that I could drop in the ReSharper plugin directory.